# Spring elasticsearch - what's the difference between IndexOperations.putmapping and IndexOperations.createWithMapping?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

Can someone please elaborate/provide example what's the difference between the two methods? I really can't understand the definition stated the docs...

Based on the docs:
CreateWithMapping - Create an index with the settings and mapping defined for the entity this IndexOperations is bound to.

PutMapping - Writes the mapping to the index for the class this IndexOperations is bound to.

What does "mapping" mean under CreateWithMapping() method? Is it the field mappings (text, keyword etc)?

Answer (score 0):

For information about what mapping is in Elasticsearch, check the documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

`IndexOperations.putMapping()` builds the mapping for the entity class that the indexOperations object was created for and writes it to the index. That index **must already exist** and it must not already have mapping properties defined for the entities properties.

`IndexOperations.createWithMapping()` builds the mapping for the entity class that the indexOperations object was created for and then creates the index with them mapping in one step. The index **must not yet exist**.